# How to Get previous days in this month PHP?

Tags: php

How to Get previous days in this month with PHP?

ex : current date = `06/05/2015`

previous days Show ==>

```
05/05/2015 
04/05/2015
03/05/2015
02/05/2015
01/05/2015
```

cordially

Comment: What you have tried???

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a quick tour of the help section. After that, you may want to edit your question a bit: Show us what you have tried so far, and why that did not help. That way you could help prevent your question being closed.

Comment: Use the DateTime and DateInterval classes ????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", "06/05/2015");
$previousDates = array();
$maxDay = $date->format("d");
for($i = 1; $i < $maxDay; $i++) {

   $previousDates[] = $date->modify("-1 day")->format("d/m/Y");

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much .. this is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Sowing previous 30 days from current days:

```
for($i=-1; $i>=-30;$i--)
  echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($i." days"));
```

> You can change date format if you want.

Comment: if month has 31 then?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get a previous day using php:

```
$prev_day = date('d.m.Y',strtotime("-1 days"));
```

to get all the previous days from the specified day, you need to do a loop:

```
$currentday = date("d");
for($i=1; $i < $currentday  ;$i++)
   {
       echo date('d.m.Y',strtotime($i."- days"))."<br/>";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$currentDate = date('d');
for($inc = 1;$inc <= ($currentDate-1);$inc++){
   echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime("-".$inc." days")).'<br/>';
}
?>
```

Try above code. Hope this will help you.

**Output:**

```
05/05/2015
04/05/2015
03/05/2015
02/05/2015
01/05/2015
```